# How to make FTP Server in Mavericks listen on IPv6 interfaces?

Tags: macos, networking, ftp, ipv6, osx-mavericks

Althought native IPv6 connectivity is not yet possible with my ISP, I can access IPv6 websites via 6to4 tunnel. The Server App in Mac OS X Mavericks comes with FTP features. However it seems to accept IPv4 connections only. What should I do to enable it to listen on IPv6 interfaces?